# ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders not working

Tags: spring, property-placeholder

I am using ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders in my spring context.
as below.

```
<bean
        class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="locations">
            <list>
                <value>classpath:messaging.properties</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="ignoreResourceNotFound" value="false" />
        <property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="true" />
    </bean>
```

event setting ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders to true its not ignoring my spring bean being injecting.
i am passing amq.topic=  in property file for

```
<bean id="messageTopic1" class="org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQTopic">
        <constructor-arg value="${amq.topic}" />
</bean>
```

But its not ignoring this bean for being injecting.

below is my Spring-context.xml amd property file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd">

    <bean
        class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="locations">
            <list>
                <value>classpath:messaging.properties</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="ignoreResourceNotFound" value="false" />
        <property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="true" />
    </bean>


    <!-- Active MQ Broker Configuration Details -->

    <bean id="connectionFactory" class="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory">
        <property name="brokerURL" value="${amq.url}" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="messageQueue1" class="org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQQueue">
        <constructor-arg value="${amq.queue}" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="messageTopic1" class="org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQTopic">
        <constructor-arg value="${amq.topic}" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="jmsTemplate" class="org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate">
        <property name="connectionFactory" ref="connectionFactory" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="activeMQ" class="com.isc.common.messaging.AmqUtilityHelper">
        <property name="destination" ref="messageQueue1" />
        <property name="jmsTemplate" ref="jmsTemplate" />
    </bean>

    <!-- <bean id="activeMQ1" class="com.isc.common.messaging.AmqUtilityHelper">
        <property name="destination" ref="messageTopic1" />
        <property name="jmsTemplate" ref="jmsTemplate" />
    </bean> -->

    <bean id="messageBroker" class="com.isc.common.messaging.AmqUtilityHelper">
        <property name="activeBroker" value="${active.broker}" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

And Below is the property file that i am loading.

```
#AMQ/Solace properties production:
# uncomment the borker to use
active.broker=activeMQ
#active.broker=solace
#active.broker=activeMQ



#AMQ Broker Properties
amq.url=failover:(tcp://localhost:61616)??initialReconnectDelay=2000&maxReconnectAttempts=5
amq.queue=messageQueue1
amq.topic=


#Solace Broker Properties
solace.url=smf://192.168.56.101:55555
solace.userName=spring_user@Solace_Spring_VPN
solace.passWord=spring_password
solace.jndiName=JNDI/CF/spring1
solace.queue=JNDI/Q/requests
#solace.topic=JNDI/topic1
```

Comment: are you able to resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

> By default, ApplicationContext implementations eagerly create and
>   configure all singleton beans as part of the initialization process.
>   Generally, this pre-instantiation is desirable, because errors in the
>   configuration or surrounding environment are discovered immediately,
>   as opposed to hours or even days later. When this behavior is not
>   desirable, you can prevent pre-instantiation of a singleton bean by
>   marking the bean definition as lazy-initialized. A lazy-initialized
>   bean tells the IoC container to create a bean instance when it is
>   first requested, rather than at startup.

Can you please try to lazily initialize your bean using below construct.

> lazy-init="true"

```
   <bean id="messageTopic1" class="org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQTopic" 
  lazy-init="true">
            <constructor-arg value="${amq.topic}" />
    </bean>
```

Comment: Its working if i comment out spring bean.<!-- <bean id="activeMQ1" class="com.isc.common.messaging.AmqUtilityHelper">
        <property name="destination" ref="messageTopic1" />
        <property name="jmsTemplate" ref="jmsTemplate" />
    </bean> --> But i dont want to comment out bean which is refering to bean id="messageTopic1"  so how to stop lazy-init="true" spring bean being refereed by other spring beans.